# Debugging view by adding borderColor in lldb

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, lldb

I'm trying to use lldb to add a border to a particular view during debugging to modify it at runtime.

For example, I put a breakpoint somewhere in my code and do in lldb :

```
(lldb) p [[self.scrollview layer] setBorderWidth:1]
```

This work great, but now I want to change the border Color but I'm getting errors :( .
Here what I tried :

```
(lldb) p [[self.scrollview layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]]
error: no known method '-CGColor'; cast the message send to the method's return type


(lldb) po [[self.scrollview layer] setBorderColor:(CGColor*)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]]
error: use of undeclared identifier 'CGColor'


(lldb) p [[self.scrollview layer] setBorderColor:(id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]]
error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'CGColorRef' (aka 'CGColor *') with an rvalue of type 'id'


(lldb) p [[self.scrollview layer] setBorderColor:(void*)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]]
error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'CGColorRef' (aka 'CGColor *') with an rvalue of type 'void *'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Edited as my answer was incorrect.)*

It appears you need to cast this to hell and back:

`[[self.scrollview layer] setBorderColor:(CGColorRef)[(id)[UIColor redColor] CGColor]]`

Comment: Nice ! I thought I tried this one :( !
Btw, the `(id)` before `[UIcolor ...` seems useless in this case.